# How to reown a process?

Tags: process, tty, pty, disown

when i run this script with a shortcut(sxhkd):

```
#!/bin/sh

MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/music"

songs=$(ls "$MUSIC_DIR")

filename=$( echo -e "random\n$songs" | dmenu -l 30 -i -p "Play >> ")

if [[ $filename = "random" ]]
then
    filename=$(ls "$MUSIC_DIR" |shuf -n 1)
fi

if [[ -f "$MUSIC_DIR/$filename" ]]
then
    notify-send -t 2500 "$filename is playing" &&  mpv "$MUSIC_DIR/$filename" --no-audio-display
else
    notify-send -t 1500 "typo?"
fi
```

I want to open a terminal control mpv process on it ( get the mpv terminal interface ).

I have tried reptyr, but I'm getting this error.

```
~ λ  reptyr $(pgrep mpv)
[-] Process 514610 (dmenuMusic) shares 514636's process group. Unable to attach.
(This most commonly means that 514636 has sub-processes).
Unable to attach to pid 514636: Invalid argument
```

also tried:

```
~ λ  echo 0 | doas tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

It just didn't work, gave me same error.

Comment: To the new terminal: [`reptyr`](https://superuser.com/a/1231033/432690). The process *won't* become a child of the new shell though.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my try. I didn't have success using that

Comment: thanks for the respond @KamilMaciorowski , when i run mpv from a terminal it gives me an interface that i can use to loop, increase volume, etc.. . but i have a shortcut that runs a script dmenuMusic which runs mpv. so i need a way to open a terminal and get this interface, use it , and bg disown the proccess again and exit the terminal

Comment: Have you considered getting used to `tmux` or `screen`?

Comment: yeah, sometimes. but i don't understand what this have to do with my question?
you mean start the command in tmux session and retrive it when i need it? 
if this is what you mean then i need to start a tmux everytime i start a song and it makes it complicated. plus if reowning a proccess worked it opens many more use cases.

Comment: `tmux` is fully scriptable. You have a shortcut that runs some script anyway. *But* I don't know what "script dmenuMusic" is and how it affects things. Anyway, I have just tested and `reptyr` *can* do what you want to do, when the command is exactly `mpv song.mp3 & disown`. So I think your problem with it is because of dmenuMusic, whatever it is. I guess the question does not show us the actual command, i.e. it's not [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019). And probably it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You want to control `mpv`, not necessarily to reown it.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience I have edited my questino to be more MCVE.

Comment: Side note: [parsing the output of `ls` is not a good practice](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Side note: `[[ ... ]]` is not valid `sh` syntax. That first line should reference `bash` rather than `sh` - or you should replace the conditional test with one that fits `sh`

Comment: thanks for the notes.